# Is the following interval connected in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Consider the interval $[0,2]$, is it connected?

I think it is disconnected because we can write it as a union of 2 open sets in its subspace topology:

$[0,2] \subset [0,1] \cup (1,2]$ and both $[0,1]$ and $(1,2]$ are open in $[1,2]$.

Is this right?

EDIT: I changed the subsets of $[1,2]$ mentioned above, I think i's now right..?

Comment: $(-1,1] \cap [0,2] = [0,1]$ is not open in $[0,2]$. The connected subsets of $R$ are precisely the intervals.

Comment: $[0,2]= (-1,1] \cup (1,2]$? Are you sure?

Comment: @quasi oh, I have just edited it

Comment: How is $(-1,1]$ open in the subspace topology of $[1,2]$? It's not even a subset.

Comment: How is $[0,1]$ open in $[0,2]$?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is wrong. The set $[0,1]$ is *not* an open subset of $[0,2]$ in the subspace topology. There is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)\cap[0,2]\subset[0,1]$.